Window folding or rolling up with title bar visible
I recently moved to Ubuntu Gnome from Manjaro Xfce. Is there a way to fold the window with title bar visible like it is in Manjaro Xfce? I have Xfce in Ubuntu too but not a huge fan. Gnome is way better. I am a developer, so would be great if I could keep the folded window visible and reachable instead of minimizing.
